# access powershell using proc_open in php

Tags: powershell-1.0

please help me,

I have problem how to use powershell on php to manage my distribution group on office365 Microsoft.Exchange :

1.First I'm using exec() command on php. It's working very well but have a problem on how to keep powershell open in background and would be able to access it again with the same PPSession(to avoid re-login and Import-PSSession again from Miscosoft.Exchange). This's my php code

```
$output = array();
$return_code = 0;
$last_line = exec('powershell.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\powershell\powerscript.ps1  ', $output, $return_code);

echo "<pre>";
 print_r($output); 
echo "</pre>";
```

2.I'm try to use proc_open() in php. I's working on cmd.exe but it is not working on powershell.exe. This my sample code

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array("file", "error.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);    

// if cmd.exe it's working
$process = proc_open('powershell.exe', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'write-host test' . PHP_EOL);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

echo( '<pre>' );
print_r(stream_get_contents($pipes[1]));
echo( '<pre>' );

fclose($pipes[1]);
proc_close($process);
}
```

If anyone has experience on how to use Powershell in PHP, please share with me.

Best Regard
Made Edy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact dynamically with a real Powershell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shellObj    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('powershell');

$strCmd1   = 'command one from script';
$return1  = $shellObj->exeCmd($strCmd1);

$strCmd2   = 'command two from script';
$return2  = $shellObj->exeCmd($strCmd2);

//etc, etc
```

Instead of triggering a single script you can just trigger each command individually and handle the return. You can issue any command you like against the $shellObj, the environment is maintained throughout the life of the PHP script.